# Get rid of sqare bracers. Or how to get actual string

Tags: java, automated-tests, rest-assured-jsonpath

I'm getting trough initial very first blind steps of rest-assured with Java.

I have few requests, which actually works well and I started to add assertions.
So I'm sending request, getting JSON as response, extracting it. And I need to verify if part of it equals to "success".

I'm taking it as

```
Response res = given().
when().post("/profile").then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().response();

rc3 = res.path("op_list.msg").toString();

System.out.println(rc3);
```

So output looks like array according to `toString` method's documentation. Surely, assertion won't work :( it sees difference between

> [success]

and

> success

Substrings is not recommended by internal code requirements. I just thought I'm using wrong method, but didn't find any besides `asString`, but it won't work with path expression.
I have no any clue or relative search results. If you would help me with advice I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Well have you tried to substring it?

Something like `rc3.substring(0,rc3.length()-1)` should do the job, another solution would be to use `replaceAll` method, or maybe to use some JSON parsing library.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can `substring` your output.
2. You can use `contains()` method of `String` class.
3. You can use Jackson to convert it to Java Object. See [Jackson Blog](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html)

Comment: substrings is not recommended by internal code requirements :( they said it's a smell code lol. Thank you for java object convert direction. I just thought I'm using wrong method, but didn't find any besides asString, but it won't work with path expression. Works with whole JSON answer :(

Answer (score -1):

You could possibly try the below:

String Input = "[success]";

String replacedInput = Input.replaceAll("[,]","");

Hope this helps!

Comment: it outputs same [success] with `println`

Comment: This is not my DV :(